# Will log probabilities mess up the computation of precision recall curve in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am trying to compute Precision-Recall AUC. I am using [`metrics.precision_recall_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) for that.

`precision, recall, thresholds = metrics.precision_recall_curve(gold, scores, pos_label=1)`

Here `gold` is a list with `0`s and `1`s. `scores` is the list of log probabilities (instead of the actual probabilities).

Once I get the precision and recall arrays I use `[metrics.auc][2]` to compute Precision-Recall AUC.

`pr_auc = metrics.auc(recall, precision)`

Will this computation be incorrect if since I am using log probabilities instead of the real probabilities?

Comment: If you take `np.exp(scores)` instead of scores you will lose the log and it should be correct

Comment: In general the ROC curve is defined in terms of an arbitrary score, and the problem is to count false positives and true positives at different thresholds on the score. In that scenario, an arbitrary monotonic transformation of the scores preserves ordering, and therefore the FP, TP counts if the transformation is increasing (and reverses order if decreasing). I don't know about sk-learn but if it conforms to that usual scheme, then working with log-whatever is equivalent to whatever.